# Yaml-cpp (new API) - nested map / sequence combinations and iteration

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

I'm having quite fundamental problems with this api's handling of maps vs sequences.  Say I have the following structure:

```
foo_map["f1"] = "one";
foo_map["f2"] = "two";
bar_map["b1"] = "one";
bar_map["b2"] = "two";
```

I want this to be converted to the following YAML file:

```
Node: 
    - Foo:
      f1 : one
      f2 : two
    - Bar:
      b1 : one
      b2 : two
```

I would do so by doing:

```
node.push_back("Foo");
node["Foo"]["b1"] = "one";
...
node.push_back("Bar");
```

However at the last line node has now been converted from a sequence to a map and I get an exception.  The only way I can do this is by outputting a map of maps:

```
Node:
    Foo:
      f1 : one
      f2 : two
    Bar:
      b1 : one
      b2 : two
```

The problem with this is if I cannot read back such files.  If I iterate over Node, I'm unable to even get the type of the node iterator without getting an exception.

```
YAML::Node::const_iterator n_it = node.begin();

for (; n_it != config.end(); n_it++) {
        if (n_it->Type() == YAML::NodeType::Scalar) {
            // throws exception
        }
    }
```

This should be very simple to handle but has been driving me crazy!

Comment: I would prefer and suggest [this kind of structure](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=Node%3A+%0A++++-+type%3A+Foo%0A++++++f1+%3A+one%0A++++++f2+%3A+two%0A++++-+type%3A+Bar%0A++++++b1+%3A+one%0A++++++b2+%3A+two%0A&type=json).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The YAML file

```
Node: 
    - Foo:
      f1 : one
      f2 : two
    - Bar:
      b1 : one
      b2 : two
```

is probably not what you expect. It is a map, with a single key/value pair; the key is `Node` and the value is a sequence; and each entry of that sequence is a map with *three key/value pairs*, and the value associated with, e.g., the `Foo`, is null. This last part is probably not what you expected. I'm guessing you wanted something more like what you actually got, i.e.:

```
Node:
    Foo:
      f1 : one
      f2 : two
    Bar:
      b1 : one
      b2 : two
```

The question now is how to parse this structure.

```
YAML::Node root = /* ... */;
YAML::Node node = root["Node"];

// We now have a map node, so let's iterate through:
for (auto it = node.begin(); it != node.end(); ++it) {
  YAML::Node key = it->first;
  YAML::Node value = it->second;
  if (key.Type() == YAML::NodeType::Scalar) {
    // This should be true; do something here with the scalar key.
  }
  if (value.Type() == YAML::NodeType::Map) {
    // This should be true; do something here with the map.
  }
}
```

Comment: "It is a map, with a single key/value pair" - [no, it's not](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=Node%3A+%0A++++-+Foo%3A%0A++++++f1+%3A+one%0A++++++f2+%3A+two%0A++++-+Bar%3A%0A++++++b1+%3A+one%0A++++++b2+%3A+two%0A&type=json).
You and op probably think of something [like this](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=Node%3A+%0A++++-+Foo%3A%0A++++++++f1+%3A+one%0A++++++++f2+%3A+two%0A++++-+Bar%3A%0A++++++++b1+%3A+one%0A++++++++b2+%3A+two%0A&type=json), to keep the orders of his objects.

Comment: Thanks I will make better use of the online YAML parser from now on so I can see what is going on