# Writing nested maps and sequences to a yaml file using YAML::Emitter

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

I have been trying to output a yaml file using YAML::Emitter. For instance, I need something like this to be my yaml file.

```
annotations:
  - run:
     type: range based
     attributes:
      start_frame:
       frame_number: 25
      end_frame:
       frame_number: 39
```

So far, using my code

```
for (auto element : obj)
{
    basenode = YAML::LoadFile(filePath);  //loading a file throws exception when it is not a valid yaml file

    //Check if metadata is already there
    if (!basenode["file_reference"])
    {
        writeMetaData(element.getGttStream(), element.getTotalFrames(), element.getFileHash());
    }

    annotationNode["annotations"].push_back(element.getGestureName());

    annotationNode["type"] = "range based";
    output << annotationNode;

    attributesNode["attributes"]["start_frame"]["frame_number"] = element.getStartFrame();

    attributesNode["attributes"]["end_frame"]["frame_number"] = element.getEndFrame();

    output << typeNode;
    output << attributesNode;

    ofs.open(filePath, std::ios_base::app);
    ofs << std::endl << output.c_str();
}
```

I am getting an output like this

```
annotations:
  - run
type: range based
---
attributes:
 start_frame:
  frame_number: 26
 end_frame:
  frame_number: 57
```

I want the "type" and "attributes" under the recently pushed sequence item into the "annotations" and subsequently the same for all the following nodes.

I even tried using something like this

> annotationNode[0][type] = "range based"

and the output was like this

> 0: type: "range based"

How do i get the recently pushed item in the sequence "annotations"?

Comment: It's more helpful to write complete examples; your code is reasonably thorough, but it doesn't show what types your variables are (e.g., when is `annotationNode` defined?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're building up your root node, `annotationNode`, then just build it up and output it once. You wouldn't need to write either the `typeNode` or `attributesNode` to the emitter. For example, you might write

```
YAML::Node annotationNode;
for (auto element : obj) {
  YAML::Node annotations;
  annotations["name"] = element.getGestureName();
  annotations["type"] = ...;
  annotations["attributes"] = ...;
  annotationNode["annotations"] = annotations;
}

output << annotationNode;
```

Comment: Thank you Jesse for your answer. I already implemented it and its working. Maybe i didn't put my question clearly. I need the "name"  as a sequence item and add childs to it and subsequently following items with childs. Something like [this](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=Node%3A+%0A++++-+Foo%3A%0A++++++++f1+%3A+one%0A++++++++f2+%3A+two%0A++++-+Bar%3A%0A++++++++b1+%3A+one%0A++++++++b2+%3A+two%0A&type=json)

Comment: Perhaps clarify your question? And if you have a solution working, feel free to write it as a solution, so that others who have your question can see the solution.

Comment: i followed your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504708/yaml-cpp-new-api-nested-map-sequence-combinations-and-iteration) as reference for this. I would mark your comment as an answer but i still don't know how to achieve format like shown [here](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=Node%3A+%0A++++-+Foo%3A%0A++++++++f1+%3A+one%0A++++++++f2+%3A+two%0A++++-+Bar%3A%0A++++++++b1+%3A+one%0A++++++++b2+%3A+two%0A&type=json)